# objective-c equivalent to c++ numeric_limits::max()

Tags: objective-c, numeric-limits

I've gotten used to utilizing the numeric_limits part of the C++ STL for initializing numeric types (int,float, etc.) to their largest possible value. 
I.e. int i=numeric_limits::max()

Is there an equivalent to this in objective-c? I've seen using INT_MAX and FLT_MAX in google searches, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is:

`NSIntegerMax`, `NSIntegerMin`, `CGFLOAT_MAX` etc.

These are sufficient for getting the numeric limits.

Comment: Any time! And welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way. When you find answers that help you give them an up vote, and if they answer your question, accept them with the check mark to the left. Have fun!

Comment: What about short type? I could not find it.